# How to increase the value of a `Fin n` without increasing its index?

Tags: agda, idris

When trying to implement a `mod : Nat -> (m : Nat) -> Fin m` function on Idris, I noticed the obvious algorithm wouldn't work because, when looping around and when increasing the result, Idris won't believe it is still within range. This snippet explains the problem:

```
-- (M : Nat) is the modulus, doesn't change
-- (r : Fin M) is the result, increases as you recurse
-- (n : Nat) is the dividend, the recursion stops when it is 0
-- (m : Nat) is the modulus index, when it is Zero, the result loops around
modAux : (M : Nat) -> (r : Fin M) -> (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> Nat

-- When `n` is Zero, we're done, so, return result (works!)
modAux M r Z m = r

-- When `n > 0` but `m` iz zero, the result must loop around
-- Problem: `Z` is not a valid `Fin M`!
modAux M r (S n) Z = modAux M Z n M

-- when `n > 0` and `m > 0`, decrease both and increase the result
-- Problem: `(S r)` is not a valid `Fin M`!
modAux M r (S n) (S m) = modAux M (S r) n m
```

To implement `modAux`, it seems like we need a `suc : Fin n -> Fin n` function that loops around. I had trouble implementing that, too. When looking at Agda's standard lib implementation of `mod`, I noticed it first proves `mod-lemma : (acc d n : ℕ) → let s = acc + n in mod-helper acc s d n ≤ s`, to, then, implement `mod` by using `Fin.fromℕ≤″`. That looks heavy. Is there any alternative way to increase a `Fin n` value without increasing its index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
open import Function
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Fin renaming (zero to fzero; suc to fsuc) using (Fin)

suc-around : ∀ {n} -> Fin n -> Fin n
suc-around {0}     ()
suc-around {suc _} i  = go id i where
  go : ∀ {n m} -> (Fin n -> Fin (suc m)) -> Fin n -> Fin (suc m)
  go {1}           k  fzero   = fzero
  go {suc (suc _)} k  fzero   = k (fsuc fzero)
  go               k (fsuc i) = go (k ∘ fsuc) i
```

The idea is that you need to decide whether to return `Fin.suc i` or `Fin.zero` in the very end of processing a `Fin n`. I.e. when you make recursive calls, you do not know whether the computation will result in an additional `Fin.suc` or `Fin.zero` will be returned. This choice can be made only in the base case where you know that the argument of type `Fin` is actually `Fin.zero`. This is what these two lines are responsible for:

```
  go {1}           k  fzero   = fzero
  go {suc (suc _)} k  fzero   = k (fsuc fzero)
```

If there is no room for another `Fin.suc` (i.e. the argument actually has the `Fin 1` type), then simply return `Fin.zero`. But if it's possible to apply another `Fin.suc` without changing the type, then do it and also apply the continuation which consists of `Fin.suc`s collected so far while performing recursive calls:

```
  go               k (fsuc i) = go (k ∘ fsuc) i
```

So the main idea is that you need to choose what to return in the base case, hance in the recursive case you only make sure that you don't lose the information of how many `Fin.suc`s have been processed.

Regarding `mod` itself I like [this](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/misc-stuff/blob/2c93645ab413c7af0f61819cd65ed4e399320808/agda/DivMod.agda) implementation by [András Kovács](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068232/andr%C3%A1s-kov%C3%A1cs).

Answer (score 5):

`Data.Fin.strengthen` can do the heavy work.

```
-- Data.Fin.strengthen : Fin (S n) -> Either (Fin (S n)) (Fin n)
-- conceptually
-- strengthen Data.Fin.last = Left last
-- strengthen n = Right n
```

Personally, I don't like this function because its output is "too big"; it usually doesn't use all the `Left` values it says it can return, but it's in the standard library and it works.

```
rotateUp : Fin n -> Fin n
rotateUp {n = Z} _ impossible
rotateUp {n = S k} f = either (const FZ) FS $ strengthen f
```

I don't recommend writing `modAux` directly. I'd rather express `mod` in terms of this function, which is more general:

```
toChurchNat : Nat -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
toChurchNat Z _ x = x
toChurchNat (S n) f x = toChurchNat n f (f x)
```

Which converts a `Nat` into its Church representation (a function that repeats any endofunction some number of times). Thus:

```
mod : Nat -> (divisor : Nat) -> {auto prf : IsSucc divisor} -> Fin divisor
mod dividend (S divisor') = toChurchNat dividend rotateUp FZ
```